# Wingpanel on Debian Jessie

Tags: wingpanel

Some months I use gala from elementary OS stable repositories on Debian Jessie + xfce. Working perfect. Recently I installed new wingpanel from ppa:elementary-os/staging. It installs without problems, but system tray isn't displayed. Only this indicators on panel: calendar, network, notifications and session indicator. Panel crashing after installation keyboard indicator. I can't understand why the system tray isn't displayed and why panel crashing after installation keyboard indicator.

Only this in terminal:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 10:55:56.661879] Application.vala:155: System Panel version: 2.0
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 10:55:56.661954] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 10:55:56.668387] IndicatorFactory.vala:49: Unable to read indicators: There is no such file or directory
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 10:55:56.689326] [Gtk] Failed to parse /home/evil/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini: The file of keys doesn't begin with group
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.731891] [Gtk] gtk_widget_get_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.731930] System Panel will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.742305] file /build/wingpanel-indicator-session-II9w3t/wingpanel-indicator-session-0.1+r30+pkg5~daily~ubuntu0.3.1/src/Indicator.vala: line 138: unexpected error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.742347] System Panel will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.742386] [Gtk] gtk_container_add: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.742410] System Panel will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.742889] file /build/wingpanel-indicator-session-II9w3t/wingpanel-indicator-session-0.1+r30+pkg5~daily~ubuntu0.3.1/src/Indicator.vala: line 118: unexpected error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.742929] System Panel will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.775501] DeviceManager.vala:93: Updating UPower properties failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property OnLowBattery
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.775540] System Panel will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.775954] [Gtk] gtk_widget_get_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 10:55:56.775989] System Panel will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 10:55:56.954923] [Gtk] Invalid icon size 24
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Debian and not elementary OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the new wingpanel and it's indicators are work in progress and are not ready for productive use.

The keyboard indicator is listening on the `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` gsettings entry. Maybe you don't have it. It also depends right now on the switchboard keyboard plug for the layouts file.

Btw. you also have installed wingpanel-indicator-ayatana which only works on ubuntu. Also you are missing some dbus interfaces which the indicators depends on (probably you have the wrong versions since you are on debian).

Alucryd managed to make it work on arch. Maybe you can look up something there.
https://github.com/alucryd/aur-alucryd/tree/master/pantheon

Comment: Thanks for answer. I add [('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru')] to "sources" in org.gnome.desktop.input-sources entry and add layouts.txt from freya to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/switchboard/hardware/. Now keybord applet working, but not change layouts.